# Castle windsor resolution pipeline with Unity as sub resolver

Tags: c#, unity-container, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Shortly speaking I am trying to link `Castle Windsor` container with `Unity`container. Let me explain the context:

I have a project in which for very long time it used castle windsor. A few days ago, I got a bunch of dll's that I must consume / use from my old project. Those DLL's use Unity Container as their injection mechanism. I also have access to interfaces / implementations that are found in those dlls but I would not try to instantiate manually implementations but I would just prefer, if possible, to link the Unity container with my current castle windsor container. How could I achieve this?

So if I have:

```
public class MyService: IService 
{
    public MyService (IThidPartyService thirdParty) 
    {

    }
}
```

If I resolve `IService` with windsor it would be nice that `IThirdPartyService` to be solved by the other container: Unity.

Thank you!.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a perfect example for the use of a custom [`ISubDependencyResolver`](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/resolvers.md). Whenever Castle won't know how to resolve a specific dependency it will address that custom resolver. That new resolver will depend on the Unity Container and will use it to resolve "for" Castle.

[Castle's documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/how-dependencies-are-resolved.md#how-dependencies-are-resolved) states that:

> If previous places weren't able to resolve the dependency resolver
>   will ask each of its sub resolvers (ISubDependencyResolver) if they
>   can provide the dependency.

So when that dependency will not be found in Castle it will seek your new resolver which will provide the dependency.

Here is a working example with both **Constructor Injection** and **Property Injection**:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IDependency, Dependency1>();
        unityContainer.RegisterType<IPropertyDependency, PropertyDependency1>();

        WindsorContainer castleContainer = new WindsorContainer();
        castleContainer.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new UnityResolver(unityContainer));
        castleContainer.Register(
           Component.For<SomeType>());

        var result = castleContainer.Resolve<SomeType>();
    }
}

public interface IDependency { void Foo(); }
public class Dependency1 : IDependency { public void Foo() { } }

public interface IPropertyDependency { }
public class PropertyDependency1 : IPropertyDependency { }
public class SomeType
{
    public SomeType(IDependency dependency) { ConstructorDependency = dependency; }

    public IDependency ConstructorDependency { get; private set; }
    public IPropertyDependency PropertyDependency { get; set; }
}

public class UnityResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    public UnityResolver(UnityContainer container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }
    public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return Container.Registrations.Any(z => z.RegisteredType.Equals(dependency.TargetType));
    }

    public object Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return Container.Resolve(dependency.TargetType);
    }

    public UnityContainer Container { get; set; }
}
```

And the result:

[image]

*As for the code for checking `Unity` for the `CanResolve` - I'm sure it can be improved - I do not know much about Unity*

Comment: I've tried this. The ideea is that ... HOW would castle know that he has to inject a specific interface through property injection? The only way he could know is by having that interface in the dependency map. Otherwise he would not even try to inject it.

Comment: @GeorgeLica - As for property injection it doesn't seem to me to be a problem - [See documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/how-dependencies-are-resolved.md#how-dependencies-are-resolved)

Comment: @Alexandru Marculescu - Please consider awarding the bounty :) The answer solves this question

Comment: @GeorgeLica - Did the solution above help you solve the problem?